# When does a Proximity Alert fire?

Tags: android, android-intent

Does a Proximity Alert fire an Intent only when the device enters (or leaves) an area, as in the device was not previously in the area but enters the area? So if my app made a Proximity Alert around the device location, would the Proximity Alert fire an Intent immediately? Or would it simply not fire an Intent?

Comment: Have you tried it out? That would be a simple way to tell.

Answer (score 0):

The event will be fired when the sensor reports the change. On a normal Android phone, it will be triggered when:

1. The phone face is moving close to an object, the event will be fired at the time when the distance reduced to less than the threshold
2. The phone face is moving far from an object, the event will be fired at the time when the distance increased to larger than the threshold

The threshold is normally 5 cm.